# От чего блокируется прокрутка страницы

Tags: angular

Этот вапрос я уже задал несколько раз, и сейчась просто хочу узнать от чего вообще возможно такое повидение. Я изпользую Angular 7 , и по моему какое то событие блокирует прокрутку, но как его найти? Я открыл консол и из Event Listeners  удалил все событие на всех элементах, кроме scroll, но и это не помогло. Можете дать какой то совет пожалуйста. Скажу еще такой нюанс, сначало прокрутка нормально работает, и когда mat-checkbox элемент checked, тогда и все сломается, css тут не причем, я удаляю из консоли весь css.

Comment: В прошлый раз мы выяснили, что дело в chart.js. Почему вы не упоминаете его? Скорее всего вам и на этот вопрос ничего не ответят - способов заблокировать скролл, скорее всего, несколько десятков. Никто и никогда их перечислять не будет.

Comment: Потому что они в месте блокируют, если я удаляю лыбо mat-checkbox лыбо canvas chart.js то тогда все нормально работает, я хочу узнать хоть кокие то идеи

Comment: Да, вероятность получить ответ на ваш вопрос в такой формулировке - не нулевая. Однако она так мала, что я готов был бы тысяч на 5-10 поспорить, что вы не получите ответа) Рад буду ошибаться

Comment: А если я сам найду?))) Сегодня уже 7-ой день и все еще не могу решать эту проблему

Comment: Скорее всего только сами вы и сможете найти ответ, т.к. у вас много сложного кода. Удалённо тут вряд ли что-то можно сделать)

Comment: Вы дали мне надежду)